# Is there a way to get the following formula (fraction) to be on 2 lines?

Tags: formatting

I would like the output of the following formula to look a bit nicer. Most importantly I would like the elements of the summations to be below them and maybe have the whole formula on 2 lines. Is this possible?
[image]

This is what I use now:

```
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{equation}
        & \textbf{maximize} \quad \dfrac{\sum_{s\in S}\sum_{t\in T} th_{out}^s(t)}{S}
        \label{eqn:1.profit}\\
\end{equation}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this?

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{mathtools}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{equation}
             \textbf{maximize} \quad \dfrac{\sum\limits_{s\in S}\sum\limits_{t\in T} th_\text{out}^s(t)}{S}
            \label{eqn:1.profit}\\
    \end{equation}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes that's absolutely perfect! thanks